# SQL Azure Reference to database and/or server name is not supported in this version sql server

Tags: sql

Would you be able to confirm whether we can reference the other database.table like below:

```
Select 
A.*,
B.*
FROM
 dbo.Test A
 INNER JOIN databaseB.dbo.Test2 B
 ON A.ID=B.ID
```

When I do above I get this error message:

> ```
> Reference to database and/or server name  is not supported in this
> ```
>
> version sql server

Any work around will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any work around will be appreciated.

According to [this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/01/sql-azure-frequently-asked-questions/) the suggestion is to do the cross-database join in your code.

> ## How can I load balance SQL Azure or do cross-database joins?
>
> Since SQL Azure databases max out at 10GB, it would be great if we could create several databases on the same server and use a view to select from all of them.  No dice – that’s not supported.  As of February 2010, your application has to know which databases to query.  **If you need to combine results from multiple databases, you’ll need to do that processing inside the application by querying all of the databases and then joining the results together in the app.**

Comment: Thanks @todda, unforutnately i'm using SSRS to joine tables on different databases.

Comment: You can join across data sources in SSRS http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/